# PHP : Construction of Multidimensional Array to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Say I have a database which has the following layout:

```
Fields:  |Business_Name| |Business_ID|

Data  :  |business_1A  | |ABC_1      |
```

I want to query the database and retrieve the business name and business ID at the same time and then encode this result to JSON for further usage. 
How do I go about doing this?

Here's some code as requested:

```
$sql = "SELECT Business_Name,Business_ID FROM biz_table";

$businessArray = array();
$bizResult = mysql_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($bizResult)) {
            $businessArray[][] = $row['Business_Name']$row['Business_ID'];
            }
            $result = json_encode($businessArray);
            echo $result;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show some existing code. In other words, work you've done. We answer questions, we don't write code for you ;)

Comment: You just described the necessary steps. Write some code and come back when you're having trouble with that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question - your question was "how do i do that?" without really giving an example of the output you want :

```
$sql = "SELECT Business_Name,Business_ID FROM biz_table";

$businessArray = array();
$bizResult = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($bizResult)) {
    $businessArray[$row['Business_Name']] = $row['Business_ID'];
}
$result = json_encode($businessArray);
echo $result;
```

$result will be

`{"business_1A" : "ABC_1" }`

Is that what you want ?

Comment: No probs - if you had put your expected output into your question you might have got more of a response ....